# Correlation between counts

Tags: r, correlation, count-data, kendall-tau

I'm trying on attendance data to find relationships between where people go. For example, say I have information on users A, B, C & D and what kinds of places they've visited in the past few months:

```
a = c(2,1,3,4)
b = c(1,0,2,5)
c = c(3,2,3,1)
d = c(0,4,1,2)
counts = cbind(a,b,c,d)
row.names(counts) = c("Concerts", "Restaurants", "Sporting Events", "Movies")
#                 a b c d
# Concerts        2 1 3 0
# Restaurants     1 0 2 4
# Sporting Events 3 2 3 1
# Movies          4 5 1 2
```

My main question is if using the Kendall correlation coefficient is appropriate here (even though the data are counts instead of ranks)? In reality this data is very sparse, which seems like it will also pose a problem. So additionally, does anyone know any methods similar to this for sparse count data?

As an example for the Kendall correlation, this is what I was thinking:

```
cor(counts[1,], counts[4,], method="Kendall")
```

Would yield -.33, presumably meaning that there's a relatively weak negative correlation in people going to movies vs. concerts (in this fictitious example).

Comment: You would expect some kind of "time budget effect" implying some (low) negative correlation, so in the analysis you should try to accomodate this, and maybe ask if there is some aditional correlation above this correlation induced by the budget constraint.